# How to fix CameraPreview error in an Android app?

Tags: android

This is the error that I'm getting but I'm not getting any **Quick Fixes** on how to fix it. It just gives me the error. I'm a newbie with fixing errors for an Android app.

The bit of code that is throwing the error:

```
Toast.makeText(CameraPreview2.this, "Cancelled!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

The error:

```
The method makeText(Context, CharSequence, int) in the type Toast is not
applicable for the arguments (CameraPreview2<detailLayout>, String, int)
```

The full code is:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            uriVideo = data.getData();
            Toast.makeText(CameraPreview2.this, uriVideo.getPath(),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        uriVideo = null;
        Toast.makeText(CameraPreview2.this, "Cancelled!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
    ...
```

Comment: The extra `Toast.LENGTH_LONG)` is a copy & paste bug just here correct, not in the code too?

Comment: What is the type of CameraPreview2? Is it an Activity or something else that extends a Context? Can you add the code for the entire file, or at least the class signature and whether or not it is in an inner class?

Comment: I believe it is an activity. I just edited my question with more code. @JonAdams

Comment: From your added code, it looks like you are not in an inner class, so you can just use `this`... You don't need the class prefix. I assume this method is in the CameraPreview2 class correct? You didn't copy & paste this into a different class that isn't CameraPreview2? You may need to paste the whole file because the above code looks fine.

Comment: The error shows that you have a generic on the class called <detailLayout>, which doesn't look familiar to me. Does that mean you are extending a custom class you wrote? Does that class extend Activity?

Comment: No, I didn't copy and paste this code into a different class that isn't CameraPreview2. Where do I put the whole code at? I'm new to all of this. Thanks for your help! @JonAdams

Comment: Just add the whole class file in the question above. Or at least the class signature anyway, because I feel that's probably the issue. Are you sure the class inherits from Context somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Impossible to say with the little bit of code you posted but `Toast.makeText(...)` does take a `Context` (which typically is something like `this` or `ClassName.this`.) i'm not sure what you passed it but clearly it isn't a Context.

Comment: so, since you didn't specify `this` as the context, you must be in an anonymous inner class of CameraPreview2?

Comment: I believe so. I didn't write the app I'm fixing it for somebody and I'm new to Android. So, how do I fix it? Thanks so much for your help! @David

Comment: uh, where is this code? in an `onClick()` (for example)? can you show the entire function? (for a quickie...why don't you try `this`?) Basically i need more code.

Comment: Ok, sorry about this. I looked at the Quick Fixes but there's many to choose from. I just posted the block of code. Thanks for your help! @David

Comment: hmmm. if it were me, i would try `this` instead of `CameraPreview2.this`. btw: what's the class this code resides in? i think you mentioned that it extends `Activity`, right?

Comment: so...what's result of replacing `CameraPreview2.this` with `this`? that should work!

Comment: That fixed it but I'm still getting the error: The method makeText(Context, CharSequence, int) in the type Toast is not
applicable for the arguments (CameraPreview2<detailLayout>, String, int) @David

Comment: you should post the entire contents of the class. something is odd that we cannot (yet?) see.

Comment: Ok, I believe I got it fixed now. Thanks! @David